# Ubuntu> Clipboard copy, SSHK

Tags: ubuntu

I have to copy the SSH Key for GitHub from id_rsa.pub. What is the clipboard utility that I could use, and what is the command line to copy to the clipboard. Done that, how to copy from the clipboard to a text file or anywhere. Please advice.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are running the X Window System, you can use the `xclip` utility.

To install: `sudo apt-get install xclip`

To copy: `xclip id_rsa.pub`

To copy to clipboard: `xclip -o | xclip -sel clip`

To paste: `xclip -o -sel clip > file.txt`

Read the README file in the `xclip` source for more on how to use it.

Comment: It did not work for me. if some one faces the same issue, you can use `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and the copy the displayed string. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SaurabhLodha What problem you found ?

Comment: It did not copy and threw an error. I don't remember the error though.

Comment: @SaurabhLodha If you got the Error again, let me know :)

Comment: @JeshwanthKumarNK Error: Can't open display: (null)

Comment: @DogBot It doesnt work if you are running without X. Example: if u are running in your serial terminal or ssh without X11 forwarding).

Comment: Doesn't work, as others have mentioned. Can't open display: (null). It doesn't work over SSH, exactly.

Comment: Should we do a normal `copy` before `copying to clipboard`?